# Sharing files Between Apps on iOS Devices

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it possible on iOS to access another app's file data? On Android, that seems possible according to following URL.
[Sharing files/ installation directory between two apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12530972/sharing-files-installation-directiory-between-two-apps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

All iOS apps are sandboxed (at least on non-jailbroken devices), and while keychain data can be shared (between Apps that share their Bundle Seed ID), doing the same for file-based data is currently not possible.

What you CAN do is pass data to other apps by exchanging them via a server or call a URL scheme that another app has registered. Apple says:

> Using a URL-based syntax, you can access data from the Web, as well as
>   pass information to other installed applications, such as Mail,
>   iTunes, and YouTube. Your own application can declare a unique URL
>   scheme, allowing any application to collaborate and share data with
>   your app.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer. Do you know any API or how to get the list of Apps that developed by the same developer or have the same bundle seed id ?

Comment: @user1785105 As far as I know, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of data. In fact, iOS apps may only share keychain data. From [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html) :

> An app ID has two parts: the team ID followed by the bundle ID search
>   string. The team ID is a 10-character string generated by Apple. Each
>   development team is assigned a unique team ID used to identify all
>   your apps. **The team ID allows you to share keychain data between apps.
>   Apps with the same team ID can share data, such as usernames and
>   passwords.** A bundle ID search string is traditionally a
>   reverse-domain-name style string. It’s the string you use in Xcode as
>   the bundle ID.

I've never done this, but there must be many tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access other app's data installed on any Apple device. It is restricted by apple.

Anyways you can try it on JailBreaked devices. These operations are handled by Apple Private API's. Which you cant access in regular devices.

If you get access to them/used in your application, apple will reject your application.